# Operation of big HEX number

Tags: javascript, hex

I am trying to implement the Diffie–Hellman key exchange. I am working with big numbers that JavaScript cannot handle in their decimal form because of memory limitation.

I want to perform the operation `g^a mod p = A` where the length of the variables is between 512 and 1536 bits.

I have no idea how to solve such equation because of the memory limitation. I cannot convert the variables into decimals and then solve it.

I tried to find JavaScript libraries used to perform math operations on Hex numbers but I did not manage to find any

**Note:**
I will be using SSL, so don't worry about JavaScript code injection.

Comment: You might find something here: [BigInteger Libraries for JS](http://www.joseprio.com/blog/2013/04/27/biginteger-libraries-for-js/). Is it really a memory problem, or that javascript uses IEEE 754 floats?

Comment: When tried to convert HEX to decimal using JS's native function parseInt(Hex, 16) it returned infinity.

Comment: I have already checked the big-integer libraries.

Comment: In Java the function that does this is called `modPow`. Perhaps you can find a JavaScript library with that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to do it.

1) Download the bigInt library. I have used this one:
http://www.leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.html

2) Use it to generate the big numbers or convert an existing number to a bigInt object.

```
We need to calculate: g^a mod p = A
```

Which can be translated into the following JavaScript code:

```
var a = randBigInt(1536);                            // Generate (a)
var p = str2bigInt(my_prime_as_string, 16);          // convert p into a bigInt
var g = str2bigInt(my_primitive_root_as_string, 16); // convert q into a bigInt

var y   = powMod(g,Y, p);    // Calculate the common secret key.
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when calculating `g^a mod p`, you don't calculate the exponent first then do the `mod`, since that way the numbers get insanely big.  Instead, you take the modulo at each step, so you never have to deal with a number bigger than `p^2`.

To calculate the exponent, you probably need to use the exponentiation by squaring algorithm, remembering to take the modulo after every squaring and after every multiplication.

See:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring (look at the basic menthod there).

But really, any good JavaScript bignum library should do this for you.

And if you have to ask, you're not competent to implement cryptographic functions yourself.  Cryptography is hard.  (E.g. the method I describe above has timing side channel attacks, so it's not suitable for more than a toy).  Find a library where someone else has already done the hard work, and learn how to use it correctly.